# How to know if this solution is continuous?

Tags: continuity, systems-of-equations

Is there a way to know if the solution $x^*(a,c)$, from a system like $$x= f(x,a) + c $$ is continuous in the variables $a$ and $c$? If there is a theorem that provide the sufficient conditions for continuity I would be very grateful to know, Thanks!

Comment: that will depend on your assumptions on $f$.

Comment: That was my first thought, but if $f$ is continuous in $a$ and $x$, I think that's not enough.

Comment: It is enough, just try to write it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x_0 = f(x_0, a_0) + c_0$.
Using the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem), if $f$ is continuously differentiable in a neighbourhood of $(x_0, a_0)$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0, a_0) \ne 1$, then there is a continuously differentiable solution $x^*(a,c)$ on a neighbourhood of $(a_0, c_0)$.